# Identifying dual space of a hyperplane in Euclidean spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I am considering a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$ given by

\begin{equation}
V=\left\{ (v_1,\ldots,v_n)\in\mathbb R^n: \sum_{i=1}^n v_i =0 \right\}.
\end{equation}

Question: Is there an explicit characterisation of the dual space $V^*$ of $V$ (specifically as vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$)?

Motivation: The space $V$ is in fact the space of signed measures on a finite state space that sum up to $0$. I am trying to characterise its dual space explicitly.

Ideas according to a friend: We know that $V^*$ is the space of all linear function on $V$. Let $\phi_1,\phi_2$ be two linear functions on $V$, which for any $v\in V$ are defined as

\begin{equation*}
\phi_1(v) = (1,1,\ldots,1)\cdot v, \ \ \phi_2(v) =(2,2,\ldots, 2)\cdot v
\end{equation*}

where $\cdot$ is the usual dot product in $\mathbb R^n$. Then by construction

\begin{equation}
\phi_1(v) = \sum_i v_i = 0 = 2 \sum_i v_i = \phi_2(v),
\end{equation}

i.e. these two operators are equal (since they agree on $V$). This somehow means that the dual space $V^*$ should have a equivalence class based definition, for instance something like

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
V^* = \Bigl\{ \left\{u+c(1,\ldots,1)\right\}: \ u\in\mathbb R^n\Bigr\},
\end{equation}

where the inner curly braces define an equivalence class (poor notation, but I am not sure how to write this correctly), i.e. $u_1\sim u_2$ if $u_2= u_1+ c(1,\ldots,1)$ for any $c\in\mathbb R$.

Issues:

(a) Is (1) the correct dual space? It feels like it since it seems to deal with the underlying constraint on $V$ in a 'reasonable' way -- $V$ has $(n-1)$ dimensions and
and somehow $V^*$ should also be $(n-1)$-dimensional which I cannot prove. If (1) is not the right dual space, then what is it? Can we characterise it?

(b) The explanation above feels ad-hoc. Is there a way to make this discussion precise(/rigorous)?

Comment: As $V$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional, $V^*$ is also $(n-1)$-dimensional. One possible way to construct it is by the means of the dual basis to any given basis. For example, take basis $e_1 = (1, 0, \dotsc, 0, -1)$, $e_2 = (0, 1, 0, \dotsc, 0, -1)$, $\dotsc$ and construct the [dual basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis) by $\epsilon^j(e_i) = \delta^j_i$.

Comment: (a) No, you wrote $V^* = \mathbb{R}^n$ (even if you meant $V^* = (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, I guess), which is $n$-dimensional, when it should be $(n-1)$-dimensional. (b) Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, you should simply find a basis and consider the associated dual basis, as suggested by Pawel Czyz.

Comment: Thanks! So using @Paweł's approach the dual basis (for $v=(v_1,v_2,-v_2-v_3)\in V$) is then given by the two functions $f_1(v)=v_1$ and $f_2(v)=v_2$. By Riesz representation this means that the dual basis is alternatively given by the vectors $\{1,0,0\}$ and $\{0,1,0\}$. Does this mean that the dual space is $\{(x,y,0)\in \mathbb R^3: x,y\in\mathbb R\}$?

Comment: The dual space is $(n-1)$-dimensional and any space of this dimensionality could act as a dual space $V^*$. The span of $\epsilon^1 = (1, 0, \dotsc, 0)$, $\epsilon^2 = (0, 1, \dotsc, 0)$, $\epsilon^{n-1} = (0, 0, \dotsc, 1, 0)$ can act as one, convenient if you plan to do operations in the basis $e_1, \dotsc, e_{n-1}$.
An alternative approach (which I find very elegant as it doesn't depend on the chosen basis of $V$) is given in Compacto's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dualising the inclusion map $i:V \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, one obtains the restriction map $i^*: (\mathbb{R}^n)^* \rightarrow V^*$, which is surjective (proving this requires Zorn's lemma, I think), and its kernel is the annihilator $V^0$.

The isomorphism theorem then gives that $V^* \equiv (\mathbb{R}^n)^*/V^0$. In an euclidean space, this can be thought as $\mathbb{R}^n$ modulo the orthogonal subspace $V^{\perp}$.

Comment: Very nice proof!
For the "dual of injective mapping is surjective", there is [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/513241/551592).

Comment: Subjectivity follows from the fact that the dimension of the kernel (easily determined) is $1$.

Comment: @Compacto. It took me a while to unpack your argument, it looks very nice. A few questions: 
(a) Which isomorphism theorem are you exactly talking about? There seem to be many versions online. 
(b) By construction $V^\perp = span\{(1,1,\ldots,1)\}$, i.e. $V^\perp$ is spanned by $n$-tuple of ones. What does $\mathbb R^n$ modulo $V^\perp$ mean precisely here? I am a little lost with the word 'modulo'. Is it close to the $V^*$ written in the question itself, i.e. the dual space consists of equivalence classes  in $\R^n$ with $v_1\sim v_2$ if $v_1=v_2+c(1,\ldots,1)$?

Comment: @UPS a) It's the theorem which says that, for every linear map $T: V\rightarrow W$, it's $V/\ker T \equiv Im T$. b) It's the quotient space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the subspace $V^\perp$, that is, the space of equivalence classes of the equivalence relation generated by $V^\perp$. In your example, it corresponds to the set of lines parallel to $(1, 1,...,1) $, which is exactly what you wrote.

Comment: @Compacto Thank you, this solved the issues (was missing the connection to quotient spaces). One last question. Do you think this way of looking at duals can be generalised to infinite dimensional vector spaces? Just wondering how much of your argument hinges on finite dimensional vector spaces. Come to think of it, the ideas about dimensions of quotient spaces definitely require finite dimensions.

Comment: @UPS My post is completely valid in infinite dimensions. It also doesn't need the underlying space to be euclidean, except for the part at the end which allows us to identify subspaces in $V^*$ with subspaces in $V$. By the way, The quotient space $V/W$ is always isomorphic to any complement of $W$. In your example, there is the obvious choice of $V$ as a complement of $V^\perp$, hence $V^*\equiv V$. The dual of $V$ is just $V$. This can also be seen by just considering that every euclidean space is isomorphic to its own dual, but I was too focused on the general, non-euclidean case.

Comment: @Compacto Thank you for the info and once more for the proof.